# Windows State of another app. handling with Java (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux

Is there any option which i can use to Control Window State of another App. from a Java Application .

Like if i need to minimize or maximize another app. window on Ubuntu Enviroment (if it's matter's im using Gnome Window Manager).

Bests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two bad options:

1) use java.awt.Robot to click the appropriate coordinates where the window is. (You have to hard code these)

2) use jni